# base table or view not found after move the site to staging

Tags: mysql, magento

Magento 1.9.2.2 moved from local to staging environment, everything works fine just one extension - magentopros_productAttachments_attachment not working,

> a:5:{i:0;s:215:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.magentopros_productAttachments_attachment' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `magentopros_productAttachments_attachment` AS `main_table`";i:1;s:5550:"#0 /var/www/public/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

But the tables are actually there, and also in core_resource table, see the screenshot.

[image]

I tried that deleted those tables and values and reinstalled the extension, it worked, but what if there is a large amount of data in the table when moving to production.

Could anyone suggest a clear fix for this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The tables appear to be there in the view, but this doesn't necessarily mean that your PHP script can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen with any good extension. Still if you are facing this kind of issue, you can take a dump of tables and data related to that particular extension and run it when you deploy to Live.

Steps
1. Take Table dump with data before making it live (magentopros_productattachments_attachment and magentopros_productattachments_attachment_product).

2. Deploy whole Database to live site.
3. Do not change core_resouce table data for extension.
4. Drop tables magentopros_productattachments_attachment and magentopros_productattachments_attachment_product.
5. Run your SQL dump in Live site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove extension table from database
2. Remove extension setup file like(`magentopros_productAttachments_setup`) from `core_resource` table.
3. Disable cache management and then run your project.

It will works.